# Can't build new MVC solution on visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

i've installed the visual studio 2013 today, but i can't create a simple new MVC solution.

Everytime i try to debug it, shows me the error:

```
"Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.

Argumento especificado estava fora do intervalo de valores válidos.
Nome do parâmetro: site

Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código. 

Detalhes da Exceção: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argumento especificado estava fora do intervalo de valores válidos.
Nome do parâmetro: site

Erro de Origem: 

Exceção sem tratamento foi gerada durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. As informações relacionadas à origem e ao local da exceção podem ser identificadas usando-se o rastreamento de pilha de exceção abaixo.

Rastreamento de Pilha: 


[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argumento especificado estava fora do intervalo de valores válidos.
Nome do parâmetro: site]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +303

[HttpException (0x80004005): Argumento especificado estava fora do intervalo de valores válidos.
Nome do parâmetro: site]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9913572
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254"
```

anyone can help me solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to kill the process ...webdev.webserr... in the Windows Task Manager.